# Checking if TIME passes through a specific time RANGE

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a specified range: 12:00pm to 12:30pm

I would like to add an extra half an hour to existing assigned hours if those hours are within the specified range.

For example, if a task was performed from 10:00 AM to 1:00 PM, I would like to add 30 minutes to the end of the task, so that end time of the task would be 1:30 PM

Any advice on how to approach this?

Edit 1:

I have fiddled around with a couple of codes, this is what I have come up with so far:

```
Public Function GetAdjEndTime(StartDateTime As Date, EndDateTime As Date) As Date
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date
    StartDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(StartDateTime, 0)
    StartTime = StartDateTime - StartDate
    EndDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(EndDateTime, 0)
    EndTime = EndDateTime - EndDate
    
    If StartTime <= #12:00:00 PM# And EndTime >= #12:30:00 PM# Then
        GetAdjEndTime = EndDate + EndTime + (1 / 48)
    Else
        GetAdjEndTime = EndDate + EndTime
    End If

End Function
```

How do you make it account for edge cases such as what happens when the date of start/end is different, what happens for tasks starting at 12:00 exactly, what happens when a job finishes at 12:15 etc?

Comment: So without any example code to look at, we can guess that this might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function

Comment: @braX I've just updated the post with some more relevant code that maybe you would be able to help me with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs a little more of a setup than you provided. But if you use the setup I picture below this formula an do the job.

```
=B6+C6+IF(AND(B6<=D$3,(B6+ C6)>C$3),(D$3-C$3),0)
```

[image: The result is in column E]

### Edit

Here's the same thing using VBA. You will need to make sure that true Date/Time values are fed as arguments.

```
Public Function AdjustedEndTime(ByVal StartDateTime As Date, _
                                ByVal EndDateTime As Date) As Date
    ' 219

    Dim Fun         As Double           ' function return value
    Dim BreakStart  As Double
    Dim BreakTime   As Double
    Dim BreakEnd    As Double
    Dim StartTime   As Double
    
    BreakStart = TimeValue("12:00")
    BreakTime = TimeValue("00:30")
    BreakEnd = BreakStart + BreakTime
    StartTime = CDbl(StartDateTime) - Int(StartDateTime)
    
    ' StartTime can't be within 3 minutes from lunch break
    If (BreakStart - StartTime) < TimeValue("00:03") Then
        EndDateTime = EndDateTime + BreakEnd - StartTime
        StartTime = BreakEnd
    End If
    
    ' add one lunch break per day
    Fun = EndDateTime + CInt(EndDateTime - StartDateTime)
    Fun = Fun + (Abs(StartTime < BreakEnd) * BreakTime)
    
    AdjustedEndTime = CDate(Fun)
End Function
```

Below is the procedure I used for testing. You may find it useful for the same purpose.

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim Dte         As Date
    Dim Duration    As Date
    
    Dte = #3/13/2021 10:15:00 AM#
    Duration = TimeValue("2:00")
    Debug.Print AdjustedEndTime(Dte, Dte + Duration)
End Sub
```

Comment: This setup is quite similar to what I have, but how would you put that into VBA though?

Comment: As you see, I have dispensed with *EndTime* because it is not known, replacing it with *Duration*. How do you intend to specify *StartTime*, especially the date, if any? How do you intend to specify *Duration* in VBA? Will this be a UDF and these values are taken from the sheet?

Comment: I have it automated such that it takes the tasks, sees how duration it has and calculates the end time, but that is not accurate, because it is missing the extra 30 minutes from the lunch break.

Comment: Where does your VBA get *StartTime* and *EndTime* (or duration) from? How do you pass these values to your function? Your code says they are "Date". A date doesn't have the time. How ***exactly*** are these values defined?

Comment: The original code is much more tedious and much more complicated of how it gets the values and how it organizes it, how it gets the input of things and etc, the only thing that I used from my code posted in the question is if statements. If you want, I can post it, but it'd take ages to explain every part of it.

Comment: The edit capture it perfectly, thank you so much!